# Pandas dataframe: Replicate rows based on condition of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe:

```
a = {'x(%)': {1: 0.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 20.0, 4: 30.0, 5: 40.0, 6: 50.0, 7: 59.8, 8: 60.0, 9: 70.0, 10: 80.0, 11: 86.6, 12: 93.2, 13: 96.6, 14: 100.0}, 'x(m)': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.6900000000000001, 3: 1.3800000000000001, 4: 2.0700000000000003, 5: 2.7600000000000002, 6: 3.45, 7: 4.1262,8: 4.140000000000001,9: 4.83, 10: 5.5200000000000005, 11: 5.9754000000000005, 12: 6.4308000000000005, 13: 6.6654, 14: 6.9}, 'Mx*': {1: -770.577, 2: -671.482, 3: -576.72, 4: -486.28, 5: -400.145, 6: -318.304, 7: -242.342,8: -240.742, 9: -167.45, 10: -98.415, 11: -55.056, 12: -13.552, 13: 6.513, 14: 26.092}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
df
     x(%)    x(m)      Mx*
1     0.0  0.0000 -770.577
2    10.0  0.6900 -671.482
3    20.0  1.3800 -576.720
4    30.0  2.0700 -486.280
5    40.0  2.7600 -400.145
6    50.0  3.4500 -318.304
7    59.8  4.1262 -242.342
8    60.0  4.1400 -240.742
9    70.0  4.8300 -167.450
10   80.0  5.5200  -98.415
11   86.6  5.9754  -55.056
12   93.2  6.4308  -13.552
13   96.6  6.6654    6.513
14  100.0  6.9000   26.092
```

I want to replicate the rows where column `x(%)` == 20.0 or 40.0 or 60.0 or 80.0:

```
     x(%)    x(m)      Mx*
1     0.0  0.0000 -770.577
2    10.0  0.6900 -671.482
3    20.0  1.3800 -576.720
3    20.0  1.3800 -576.720
4    30.0  2.0700 -486.280
5    40.0  2.7600 -400.145
5    40.0  2.7600 -400.145
6    50.0  3.4500 -318.304
7    59.8  4.1262 -242.342
8    60.0  4.1400 -240.742
8    60.0  4.1400 -240.742
9    70.0  4.8300 -167.450
10   80.0  5.5200  -98.415
10   80.0  5.5200  -98.415
11   86.6  5.9754  -55.056
12   93.2  6.4308  -13.552
13   96.6  6.6654    6.513
14  100.0  6.9000   26.092
```

Comment: A better approach than `concat` (IMO): `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['x(%)'].isin([20,40,60,80]).add(1))]`

Comment: @mozway: why is it better?

Comment: Because indexing is faster than `concat` and you don't have to sort to keep the same order.

Comment: It should be even faster with `reindex`: `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['x(%)'].isin([20,40,60,80]).add(1)))`

Comment: @mozway good points, I've removed my comment. There was another post which used the `index.repeat` approach that was also closed as a duplicate of the same post, but it would probably be good to add them to the dupe target since it has way more views

Comment: @Nick I also saw that and commented to it (and upvoted!) :)